# Select distinct records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My table

```
ANONYMOUS
ONE   TWO
1      2
2      1
1      2
3      1
```

Now i want to select distinct set of one and two.
My selected list should be

```
ANONYMOUS
    ONE   TWO
    1      2
    3      1
```

Comment: Somebody is in trouble... and it's you.  What happened to `2 | 1`?

Comment: i only want the first one with distinct set

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble: What do you mean by first? Your rows have no insertion date, so how do you know which was first?

Comment: first one mean the rows which come earlier in selection query

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble: What selection query? You haven't specified an ORDER BY so the order is undefined. They could come in any order. If you want to know which was first then you must add a column for the insertion date. MySQL even has a special type `timestamp` that makes doing exactly this very easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I guess you mean this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT one, two
FROM yourtable AS T1
WHERE one <= two
OR NOT EXISTS
(
     SELECT *
     FROM yourtable AS T2
     WHERE T1.one = T2.two
     AND T1.two = T2.one
)
```

It finds rows with `(one, two)` where the reversed pair `(two, one)` does not exist. If both exist, it chooses the pair such that `one < two`. It also selects rows where the values are equal.

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16106/1)

If you would prefer to use a `JOIN` instead of `NOT EXISTS` you can do that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.one, T1.two
FROM yourtable AS T1
LEFT JOIN yourtable AS T2
ON T1.one = T2.two
AND T1.two = T2.one
WHERE T1.one <= T1.two
OR T2.one IS NULL
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16106/2)

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble: If you are worried about performance, I think the first think you should do is try adding a multicolumn index on `(one, two)`. Measure the performance to see which of the queries is fastest.

Comment: @vol7ron: Can you define what you mean by "working" in this case? The OP didn't say what he wanted to happen in the case that the values in column one and column two are equal. I assume he wants to select those rows. If you want to not select them, change `<=` to `<`.

Comment: @MarkByers: ahh missed the `=`, I think you're right, it should work.  My apologies, just doing it in my head.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM        `ANONYMOUS` a
LEFT JOIN   `ANONYMOUS` b ON (a.one=b.two and a.two=b.one)
WHERE       b.one is null or a.one<b.one
ORDER BY    1,2
```

Comment: I typed this up before [Mark Byers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers) edited his answer.  It seems this wasn't submitted.  I'll only keep this because it might be easier to read, but his answer is fully qualified.